# how to fetch record from model through foreign key in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework. I have three different tables in yii framework.

**First Table**

First table is language(id, language_name) // id is primary key.

**Second Table**

Second Table is verse(id,topic_id, verse_text) // id is primary key, topic_id is foreign key.

**Third Table**

Third table is verse_translations(id, verse_id, language_id, translations_text) 
// id is primary key, language_id is foreign key references with language table, // verse_id is foreign key references with verse table.

**Now My Question is.**

I want to get all verse_text with specific topic_id.

So how to fetch all records from model **Verse** through foreign key i.e. topic_id and these record should be sent to view by data provider function.

At this time i am using.

**My Controller Method**

```
public function actionVerset()
    {
    $topic_id = 1;  
    $result=Verse::model()->with('topic_verse', $topic_id)->findAll();

    $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($result, array(
      'id'=>'Verse',
      'pagination'=>array(
      'pageSize'=>2,
     ),));

    $this->render('myverse',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
}
```

but it is not giving my desired result.

**My Verse Model Relation Method**

```
public function relations()
{
     return array(
    'topic' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Topic', 'topic_id'),
    'verseTranslations' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'VerseTranslations', 'verse_id'),
    'verseLanguage' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'VerseTranslations', 'language_id'),
    'topic_verse' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Verse', 'topic_id'),
    );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all Verse records with a specific topic_id, this should do the trick:

```
$records = Verse::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('topic_id' => $topic_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have declared the relation in your model you dont need to fetch the data from db using with simply use

```
 $result=Verse::model()->findAll();
```

and then when you use this

```
 $result->topic->field_name of topic table
```

This will give the result of that.